# ReactJs set indeterminate state of custom bootstrap checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I've made this checkbox which should be a "Three-State-Checkbox" it's using the indeterminate state not only as "visual-value" but also as a "real"-value. It work's fine if I'm only using the standard checkbox but if I use the bootstrap custom checkbox it doesn't work anymore because the `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).indeterminate` can't access the checkbox. 
So `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).indeterminate = true;` doesn't set indeterminate to `true`.

This is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import FormsStatic from "../FormsStatic";

class ThreeStateCheckbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: this.props.value || "0",
            checked: false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.value != "0") {
            this.state.value == "1" ? this.setState({ checked: true }) : ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).indeterminate = true;
        }
    }

    changeCbState() {
        if (this.state.value == "0") {
            this.state.value = "1";
            this.setState({ checked: true })
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).indeterminate = false;
        }
        else if (this.state.value == "1") {
            this.state.value = "2";
            this.setState({ checked: false })
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).indeterminate = true;
        }
        else {
            this.state.value = "0";
            this.setState({ checked: false })
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).indeterminate = false;
        }
        this.props.onChange(this.state.value);
    }
    render() {
        const uniqueId = FormsStatic.guid();
        return (
            <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="custom-control-input"
                    id={"others-" + uniqueId}
                    checked={this.state.checked}
                    onChange={() => {
                        this.changeCbState();
                    }}
                />
                <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor={"others-" + uniqueId}>
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ThreeStateCheckbox.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onChange: PropTypes.func
}

export default ThreeStateCheckbox;
```

What is the way to set the indeterminate of the checkbox?

Edit: in `changeCbState` I can pass the access the checkbox via eventargs (ev.target) but I also need it in `componentDidMount()`. Still have no idea how to access it there.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and use that to control the indeterminate in the DOM level:

```
constructor(props) {
    //...
    this.checkboxRef = React.createRef();
    //...
}
```

Then add the `ref` prop to your checkbox.

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    ...
    ref={this.checkboxRef}
/>
```

Now you can use the following code to set the indeterminate sate:

```
this.checkboxRef.indeterminate = true
```

Comment: `Cannot add property indeterminate, object is not extensible` i get this error with your solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution based on [this blog post](https://dev.to/gsto/how-to-build-an-indeterminate-checkbox-in-react-kbh).

**IndeterminateCheckbox.tsx**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import FormCheck, { FormCheckProps } from 'react-bootstrap/FormCheck';

export enum IndeterminateCheckboxValue {
    Unchecked,
    Checked,
    Indeterminate,
}

export interface IndeterminateCheckboxProps extends FormCheckProps {
    value: IndeterminateCheckboxValue;
}

export default function IndeterminateCheckbox(props: IndeterminateCheckboxProps) {
    const { value, ...otherProps } = props
    const checkRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (checkRef.current) {
            checkRef.current.checked = value === IndeterminateCheckboxValue.Checked
            checkRef.current.indeterminate = value === IndeterminateCheckboxValue.Indeterminate
        }
    })

    return (
        <FormCheck type="checkbox" ref={checkRef} {...otherProps} />
    )
}
```

**Usage:**

```js
<IndeterminateCheckbox value={IndeterminateCheckboxValue.Indeterminate} />
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the answer: 
@NonameSL answers was on the right way but I couldn't change the indeterminate state because the `ref` is frozen in reactjs.

My solution is to create a `ref` like this:

`this.checkboxRef = React.createRef();`

Add the `ref` to my checkbox:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    className="custom-control-input"
    id={"others-" + uniqueId}
    checked={this.state.checked}
    ref={this.checkboxRef}
    onChange={() => this.changeCbState()}
/>
```

just as @NonameSL said.

But now I can access the indeterminate state like this:

`ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.checkboxRef.current).indeterminate = true;`